# Accepting Self Answers More Frequently of Late

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, self-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I answer my own questions, even those where I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

Of late, I've been posting questions to which nobody posts an answer for a while. Since I don't just wait around for an answer, sitting on my hands, I try some slightly crazier ideas (because I usually post on SO only after I've exhausted all the "sane" ideas that I can think of). After some such experimenting, I find the solution to my post and still, nobody has provided a useful (upvote-worthy/accept-worthy) answer on my post. I am then forced to answer my own question (I don't want to delete my post just in case someone else has the same issue and Google sends them to my post) and after two days, accept it.

Is this behavior acceptable?
Why are my questions not getting good answers now more than before?
What/Should I change something about the way I post a question on SO? (the relevant questions haven't gotten many upvotes)

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter: it's not a duplicate of that question. I am aware of the protocol to answer my own question and accept it. My question is "why I am getting fewer good answers now, than before?"

Comment: I don't know that any of us can shed any light on that.  It's possible that you are dealing with more obscure problems, or it could be that the overall traffic on the tag is down for some reason.  It could be anything, honestly.

Comment: (In other words, I wouldn't take it as any reflection on you if you really haven't changed anything about your questions or their quality)

Comment: If you knew then why did you ask *Is this behavior acceptable?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to answer the question, "Why am I getting fewer good answers now, than before?". There could be any number of reasons:

- The technical difficulty of your questions has gone up
- The questions you are asking pertain to an obscure topic that not many people follow
- The quality of your questions has gone down

Regarding the acceptability of this behavior, it is perfectly fine to share knowledge using the QA format, **especially** if no one else is able to answer these questions. Accepting the answer is simply an indication of the fact that the solution worked for you.

As long as you are open to a better solution coming along and are willing to accept it if it does, there is no problem with what you are doing.

Changes you can make include:

- Making your titles less wordy / more eye catching (you'd be surprised at how important this is)
- Tagging your question strategically. Make sure your tags are broad enough to bring a wide audience, yet specific enough to get experts.
- Edit bumping your question a couple times while it's still fresh